# Dynamic file name in vars_files

Tags: ansible

The following is a simple playbook which tries to dynamically load variables:

```
site.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
  - "{{ name }}.yml"
  tasks:
  - debug: var={{ foo }}
```

Variable foo is defined in this file:

```
vars/myvars.yml
---
foo: "Hello"
```

Then playbook is run like this:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "name=myvars"
```

However this results in this error:

`ERROR! vars file {{ name }}.yml was not found`

From what I understood from several code snippets this should be possible and import the variables from myvars.yml. When trying with ansible 1.7.x it indeed seemed to work (although I hit a different issue the file name vas resolved correctly).

Was this behaviour changed (perhaps support for dynamic variable files was removed?). Is there a different way to achieve this behaviour (I can use include_vars tasks, however it is not quite suitable)?

**EDIT:** To make sure my playbook structure is correct, here is a github repository: https://github.com/jcechace/ansible_sinppets/tree/master/dynamic_vars

Comment: it's working for me on ansible 2.0.1.0, which version are you using?

Comment: 2.0.1 so maybe the fact that I am running from OSX is the issue? I will try with Linux

Comment: @arbabnazar here is a git repo with the example -- just to make sure the structure is OK. https://github.com/jcechace/ansible_sinppets/tree/master/dynamic_vars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your `site.yml` like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ name }}.yml"
  tasks:
    - debug: var={{ foo }}
```

Then run the command like this:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -e "name=myvars" -c local
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out in the mean time myself -- what confused me is that unlike include_vars task this needed the "vars" directory in path. I guess this is because one might one to use variables from non-default location in playbook file.  Nevertheless I've accepted your answer.

Comment: So happy to find this answer, because of the `{{ name }}.yml was not found` i tough my variable was not found.